# Android - Error when uploading multiple images

Tags: java, android

I got error when I tried to upload all of the images. I use `for` to loop the process, but still got error in looping. if i don't use `for`, it still can upload the image but only 1 image that will be uploaded. how can I solve this?

**UploadActivity.java**

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
filePath = intent.getStringExtra("filePath");


    ArrayList<String> flpath = new ArrayList<String>();


    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("SavedFilePathsJSONArray",
            Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String myJSONArrayString = prefs.getString("SavedFilePathsJSONArray",
            "");


    if (!myJSONArrayString.isEmpty()) {
        JSONArray jsonArray = null;
        try {
            jsonArray = new JSONArray(myJSONArrayString);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            try {
                flpath.add(jsonArray.get(i).toString());
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }



    flpath.add(filePath);

    JSONArray mJSONArray = new JSONArray(flpath);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    editor.putString("SavedFilePathsJSONArray", mJSONArray.toString()).commit();



    for (int i = 0; i < flpath.size(); i++) {
        imgFile = new File(flpath.get(i));
        if (imgFile.exists()) {
              final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                options.inSampleSize = 8;

               Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath(),options);

            ImageView myImage = new ImageView(this);
             myImage.setMaxHeight(100);
             myImage.setMaxWidth(100);
            myImage.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
            layout2.addView(myImage);
        }
    }

private class UploadFileToServer extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, String> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // setting progress bar to zero
        progressBar.setProgress(0);
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
        // Making progress bar visible
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        // updating progress bar value
        progressBar.setProgress(progress[0]);

        // updating percentage value
        txtPercentage.setText(String.valueOf(progress[0]) + "%");
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        return uploadFile();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    private String uploadFile() {

        String responseString = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < flPath.size(); i++) {
            File file = new File( flPath.get(i));
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(Config.FILE_UPLOAD_URL);

        try {
            AndroidMultiPartEntity entity = new AndroidMultiPartEntity(
                    new ProgressListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void transferred(long num) {
                            publishProgress((int) ((num / (float) totalSize) * 100));
                        }
                    });



            // Adding file data to http body
            entity.addPart("image", new FileBody(file));

            // Extra parameters if you want to pass to server
            entity.addPart("website",
                    new StringBody("www.androidhive.info"));
            entity.addPart("email", new StringBody("abc@gmail.com"));

            totalSize = entity.getContentLength();
            httppost.setEntity(entity);

            // Making server call
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity r_entity = response.getEntity();

            int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            if (statusCode == 200) {
                // Server response
                responseString = EntityUtils.toString(r_entity);
            } else {
                responseString = "Error occurred! Http Status Code: "
                        + statusCode;
            }

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            responseString = e.toString();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            responseString = e.toString();
        }
        }
        return responseString;

    }
```

**Config.Java**

```
public class Config {
 public static final String FILE_UPLOAD_URL = "http://....";

    // Directory name to store captured images and videos
    public static final String IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME = "andrd_upload";
 }
```

**error logcat**

```
01-27 16:23:45.940: W/dalvikvm(15986): threadid=12: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40fe7438)
01-27 16:23:45.950: E/AndroidRuntime(15986): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
01-27 16:23:45.950: E/AndroidRuntime(15986): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
01-27 16:23:45.950: E/AndroidRuntime(15986):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
01-27 16:23:45.950: E/AndroidRuntime(15986):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
01-27 16:23:45.950: E/AndroidRuntime(15986):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
01-27 16:23:45.950: E/AndroidRuntime(15986):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
01-27 16:23:45.950: E/AndroidRuntime(15986):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
01-27 16:23:45.950: E/AndroidRuntime(15986):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
01-27 16:23:45.950: E/AndroidRuntime(15986):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
01-27 16:23:45.950: E/AndroidRuntime(15986):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
01-27 16:23:45.950: E/AndroidRuntime(15986):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
01-27 16:23:45.950: E/AndroidRuntime(15986): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-27 16:23:45.950: E/AndroidRuntime(15986):    at com.camerafileupload.UploadActivity$UploadFileToServer.uploadFile(UploadActivity.java:228)
01-27 16:23:45.950: E/AndroidRuntime(15986):    at com.camerafileupload.UploadActivity$UploadFileToServer.doInBackground(UploadActivity.java:221)
01-27 16:23:45.950: E/AndroidRuntime(15986):    at com.camerafileupload.UploadActivity$UploadFileToServer.doInBackground(UploadActivity.java:1)
01-27 16:23:45.950: E/AndroidRuntime(15986):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
01-27 16:23:45.950: E/AndroidRuntime(15986):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
01-27 16:23:45.950: E/AndroidRuntime(15986):    ... 5 more
01-27 16:23:46.130: D/HardwareRenderer(15986): draw surface is valid dirty= null
01-27 16:23:46.180: D/HardwareRenderer(15986): draw surface is valid dirty= null
01-27 16:23:46.220: D/HardwareRenderer(15986): draw surface is valid dirty= null
01-27 16:25:29.910: D/dalvikvm(15986): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 0ms
01-27 16:25:29.950: D/dalvikvm(15986): GC_EXPLICIT freed 223K, 8% free 15337K/16583K, paused 2ms+4ms, total 38ms
```

**ScreenShoot**

[image]

**Edit**: i put the error logcat and the screenshoot of the error page (UploadActivity.java).

Comment: What is the error, specifically?

Comment: Full code where you are getting error required!!

Comment: when i check the error in logcat, it says error "for (int i = 0; i < flPath.size(); i++)". but i don't know where exactly the error is? when i click upload button after take image, it got error.